# Running multiple queries in BigQuery web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using to BigQuery web UI for running my queries. I want to delete some specific rows from all tables in a Dataset. I want to do it by running all delete queries in one go, like below:

```
DELETE FROM `dataset_name.tabl_name_1` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(user_dim.user_id, r'g_1478_h_1.') = TRUE;
DELETE FROM `dataset_name.tabl_name_2` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(user_dim.user_id, r'g_1478_h_1.') = TRUE;
DELETE FROM `dataset_name.tabl_name_3` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(user_dim.user_id, r'g_1478_h_1.') = TRUE
```

There are almost 500 tables. So there will be 500 queries to be run in one go. I have unchecked the option of 'use Legacy Sql'.

But on running above queries (almost 500) returns error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DELETE at [2:1]

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: See the answer from @Mikhail Berlyant, however if you only have a few statements to run then at least Shift + '/' can be used to quickly comment out the lines you don't want to run, allowing you to run lines one at a time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this in BigQuery web UI!

Your best option here is to use [`BigQuery client`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your preference and script those repetitive statements

Have in mind [`quotas/limitation`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements) for DML

> Edit (October 2019):

Support for [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) is now in beta. 
You can submit multiple statements separated with semi-colons and BigQuery is able to run them now.

Comment: yes. thank you Elliott, working on few of such :o)  Great stuff!!! Congratulation for getting it that far!

Comment: Thanks for advocating this new feature Mikhail!

Answer (score 0):

I get around this by putting the queries in a Cloud Function (using Python) and scheduling using the new Cloud Scheduler. Works fine, but would be easier in BQ itself.