# How do you connect series of queries in Google Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, generate-series

In Google Bigquery, I am trying to set up series of queries to run via scheduled runs. While I can set up each query to run in a scheduled run, I am looking for a solution to run one combined series of queries in a scheduled run.

What is not working is that in Bigquery, it does not let me connect series of queries by using a semicolon. So, I'm trying to figure out if there is another way to do so in Bigquery.

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, time_stamp
FROM XXA
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, time_stamp
FROM XXB
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, time_stamp
FROM XXC; 

SELECT id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.phone_number, a.email, b. call_number, b.booked, b.call_status
FROM XXD a
LEFT JOIN XXE b 
USING (unique_id);
```

When I run these queries individually, they work fine. However, when I run these two in one query (connected by semicolon), the second query starting with SELECT shows error message.

Comment: I'm guessing that your interface only allows one query to run.

Answer (score 0):

BQ will only return 1 result set at a time.  Consider the BQ web-interface...where would a second result set even go?
You are only selecting data, so if you need all of this data, consider where you are using it.  If you will be pasting the data into separate Excel sheets (for example), then running separate queries would make sense.  If these will be pasted into the same sheet, consider unioning it all together and adding *NULL* columns where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your help! To clarify, the first query (with UNION) will create a table(1) that I will need to use via JOIN with another exiting table(2) to ultimately produce a table(3). So, I only wanted the result of the table(3), which would essentially include data from table(1).

Comment: Ah.  Consider using a CTE.  **with temp as (query1) select * from temp left join other_table**

Comment: Also, similarly to what happens in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941586/running-multiple-queries-in-bigquery-web-ui), you can use the [BigQuery client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) and script your way out of the situation.
On top of that, if the answer was helpful for you, would you mind accepting it so that other users can benefit from it too =)?